# Интерактор в интеракторе или другой интерактор

Tags: android, kotlin, архитектура

Есть несколько интеракторов:

1. `ObjectsInteractor` (внутри objectsRepository, treeRepository, stateRepository)
2. `UserInteractor` (внутри userRepository)
3. `AuthInteractor` (внутри userRepository, authRepository)
4. `SecurityInteractor` (внутри securityRepository)
5. `SettingsInteractor` (внутри settingsRepository)

Необходимо очистить пользовательские данные (logout).

Первоначально сделал так:
В `SettingsViewModel` есть все перечисленные выше интеракторы, и у них во всех есть функция `clear()` - эти функции не просто перебрасывают `clear` в соответствующий репозиторий, а в некоторых есть какая то особая логика. При нажатии на кнопку `logout`, я друг за другом тяну функции `clear` у выше описанных интеракторов и при успешном выполнении цепочки выхожу на экран авторизации. Было все прекрасно :)

Но сейчас необходимо сделать функцию `logout` еще и в `SecurityView` (экран входа по паролю).

Прикинул два способа решения:

1. В принципе могу сделать также как выше в `SettingsViewModel`. Но тогда я должен буду скопировать код и каждый раз менять этот код в двух местах (может потом в трех и т.д.) при каких то изменениях, например, при logout придется еще добавить очистку чего либо или там какой то request делать(в цепочку вызова что-то добавляется).
2. Или могу сделать еще один интерактор `AppDataInteractor`и внутри него выполнять очистку всех данных, но в этом случае мне нужно будет либо копировать функции `clear` из всех выше перечисленных инеракторов и придется всегда при изменении логики этих методов менять их в соответствующих интеракторах и в `AppDataInteractor` либо мне надо в `AppDataInteractor` держать ссылки на вышеперечисленные интеракторы и вызывать их функции, а это уже совсем плохо (по феншую, один useCase не должен знать о другом).

Я даю предпочтение первому способу(так уже сделано). Что посоветуете вы?

Answer (score 0):

Я не очень уверен, что до конца вас понял но все же накину.

Я конечно не знаю сколько у вас там еще интеракторов, но если выше перечисленные это и есть все, то можно создать какой-то `abstract class/interface` и в нем иметь метод `clear()` от которого будут наследоваться/имплементировать интеракторы. При нажатии кнопки `logout()`. Можно создать какой-то хендлер который будет хранить в себе созданные экземпляры интеракторов (тут можно подумать о том, чтоб в нем были методы `add()` и `remove()`) и он имел бы метод `clear()` который пробегался бы по всем интерракторам и вызывал метод `clear()` внутри каждого (а там они везде реализованы по своему). Можно в этот метод на вход передавать какие-то фильтры и если вдруг вам необходимо чистить интеракторы по какому-то предикату.

А вообще здесь нужно видеть какие-то кейсы и код. Так очень трудно дать какой-то ответ.